# Does Google regard @type": "AggregateOffer" and "@type": "Offer" as duplication?

Tags: duplicates, aggregate, google-search-console

A site is flagging up (Google Search Console) Unparsable structured data- Duplicate unique property.

It is highlighting `@type": "AggregateOffer"` but there is only one instance of `@type": "AggregateOffer"` on any page.

As well as `@type": "AggregateOffer"` there is `"@type": "Offer"` on each affected page.

Does Google regard `@type": "AggregateOffer"` and `"@type": "Offer"` as duplication?

```js
"offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "seller": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Not real name"
},
"@type": "AggregateOffer",
"highPrice":714.32,
"lowPrice":449.12,
"priceCurrency": "GBP",
"availability": "https://schema.org/InStock"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have reworked the above code and my schema now validates:

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "Product",
"productID": "47",
"url": "https://www.webeg.uk/cpscpsprep/acatalog/Engagement-Ring-47.html",
"image": "s-Engagement.jpg",
"description":"A stunning diamond ring for the future bride....",
"itemCondition":"New",
"name": "Engagement Ring",
"offers": {
"@type": "AggregateOffer",
"highPrice":410.00,
"lowPrice":390.00,
"priceCurrency": "GBP",
"availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
"seller": {
"@type": "Organization",
"name": "Sample Company"
}
}
}
</script>
```

https://validator.schema.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.webeg.uk%2Fcpscpsprep%2Facatalog%2FEngagement-Ring-47.html

So it seems the answer is that Google does not like  @type": "AggregateOffer" and "@type": "Offer" in the same schema snippet!

Thank you.